# See an NFT Token picture in metamask

Tags: metamask, ipfs, nft

I have followed step by step this tutorial:

https://medium.com/pinata/how-to-build-erc-721-nfts-with-ipfs-e76a21d8f914

Everything works like a charm. I am working on ropsten Network.

I have create some tokens.

I have configure Metamask to see my tokens on this contract.

I can see my balance but unfortunately, i do not see the picture associated with my NFT.

Is there a way to see the picture of each token i own in metamask ?

Thanks

Comment: MetaMask just has the token ID and balance, using the ID you would ask the contract for the metadata for that NFT, and then in the metadata in your case, there is a 'hash' entry with the IPFS hash of the image.  Until MetaMask has some sort of built-in standard where you put a certain metadata key as the image data, they won't know what your NFT looks like.

Answer (score 1):

According to this [Official source](https://metamask.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/360058238591-NFT-tokens-in-MetaMask-wallet), it actually seems possible to see NFT on mobile app only.

"*Please note that while you can add NFT's as custom tokens in the extension, you will not be able to see them natively in the UI.*"

Also, Metamask warns : "*Please remember that some NFT's will not show up on the mobile app under Collectibles, or may not show up correctly.*"

In the end, my NFTs are on my Ledger and I can't connect my Ledger on mobile app without compromising my private key.

**The only easy way I found is to see them in maketplaces, like [OpenSea](https://opensea.io/).**

But maybe some NFT Museum apps, like https://www.nftmuseum.art/,  will come online soon ?

Answer (score -1):

this tutorial describes the easiest way to view your nft in metamask: https://docs.alchemyapi.io/alchemy/tutorials/how-to-write-and-deploy-an-nft/how-to-view-your-nft-in-your-wallet

Comment: Link only answers are not recommended. It is better to include the main ideas here and leave the link for more details.